# github-like comment thread for each git commit

Tags: git, github, commit, forum

Is there a tool out there that mimicks the github feature of allowing
other developers to start a comments thread for each git commit? I find this very useful, and would like to have it in my company dev environment. We use gitosis to manage
the repo, and redmine to track issues.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not really a discussion thread, but you might be interested in [`git-notes`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-notes.html).

Answer (score 0):

We are using gerrit for code review. It might be addressed to part of your question. But, it's pre-commit review system, so comments are truly associated with commits before they go into master.

See:
http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/